# Regular Expression in VBA

Tags: vba

I want to write regular expression to select Agree, Ban, compare and many more which are not followed by a preposition like by, to, with, on, for, from and many more.
e.g. if a text box or cell contains **Agree to** it should do noting but if it contains only **Agree** without any preposition regular expression should select it.
I have written below pattern but not able to get my expected output.

```
With objRgX
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(Agree|Align)[ ]?(^(to|with|on))"
End With
```

Comment: What's wrong with `^Agree$|^Align$`?  Some sample inputs would be helpful.

Comment: I have below list of words, which I want to replace 
Word New Word
Agree Agree to
Agree Agree with
Agree Agree on
Align Align with
Ban Ban from
Ban Ban in
Ban Ban on

Comment: ^^ Yoda with a stutter

Comment: I think that what @ThunderFrame is trying to say is that you'd be better off editing your list of words into the OP and adding some formatting, because it's quite difficult to determine what you're attempting to do from the unformattable text in a comment.